# Python 2.7.4 , Endless loop and no output when PoolExecutor implemented

Tags: python, python-2.7

Windows 10, Python 2.7.4

Endless loop , no output with PoolExecutor implemented

Please help , code as following:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

script_to_exec = "extract_logs.py"

d_list = ["E:\work\d_010_001.txt", "E:\work\d_010_002.txt", "E:\work\d_010_003.txt"]
i_list = ["E:\work\im_010_001.txt", "E:\work\im_010_002.txt", "E:\work\im_010_003.txt"]
output_folder_prefix = r"E:\work\output"


def get_output_folder_name(prefix, any_d):
    return prefix + \
    str("\\") + \
    str(any_d.split(".")[0].split("\\")[-1].split("d_", 1)[1])


def get_exec(d, i, output_folder_prefix ):
    process = Popen(['python', script_to_exec,
                            '-d', d,
                            '-i', i,
                            '-o', get_output_folder_name(output_folder_prefix)],
                            stdout=PIPE)
data = process.communicate()
for line in data:
    print(line)


with PoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
   for _ in executor.map(get_exec, d_list, i_list, output_folder_prefix):
       pass
```

Comment: I believe there are some exceptions in your worker. You can use `Future.result()` to get those.

Comment: You might want to consider not using an ancient Python version. If the 3.x versions aren't an option, at least upgrade to the latest 2.7.15.

Comment: `ProcessPoolExecutor` creates child process. So does`Popen`. It seems unnecessary. Use plain `map`

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor)

> The **main** module must be importable by worker subprocesses. This
>   means that ProcessPoolExecutor will not work in the interactive
>   interpreter.

The trouble with the way processes have to be created in windows means that you would need to incorporate `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` type of syntax as shown in the [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example) and run it from the terminal.

If you would like to further read into why that is, look into [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class), which is being used under the wraps for concurrent futures, and further read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) .

The summary however, would be that windows does not have an os.fork method, and so has to utilize a "cheat" to create a subprocess, which is to create an entirely new python instance and execute the script from the top to reach a similar state. This however, means that each new version needs to be given the knowledge that is it not the main thread that started the process spawning.

Answer (score 0):

You are launching Python interactively.
The interpreter's you are launching via subprocess aren't exiting after executing the script - that's why they are kept open forever.

Just a hint especially for debugging:
Have a look at stderr and check for the result code of the subprocesses:

```
def get_exec(d, i, output_folder_prefix ):
    process = Popen(['python', script_to_exec,
                            '-d', d,
                            '-i', i,
                            '-o', get_output_folder_name(output_folder_prefix)],
                        stdout=PIPE,
                        stderr=PIPE)
    data, err = sp.communicate()
    if process.returncode != 0:
        print "An error happend ..."
    for line in data:
        ...
```